# How to delete floor plan children

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have property entity and floor plan entities like this

```
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "properties", indexes = {@Index(name = "properties_parent_id_index", columnList = "parent_id", unique = true)})
public class PropertyEntity extends BaseEntity {



    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "property_id")
    private List<FloorPlanEntity> floorPlans;

....
...
}
```

now I try to delete children and save parent

like this `

```
propertyEntity.getFloorPlans().clear();
propertyDataService.save(propertyEntity);
```

but it gives exceptions like this

Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: null value in column "property_id" of relation "floor_plans" violates not-null constraint

Comment: first either delete the parent, or update the field property_id to the value of the new floorplan. This error just says that your DB has a constraint in which there must be a relation floor_plans present.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/2636929/stultuske

Comment: I dont have a new floor plan just want to remove them and save

Comment: which is not possible because of the constraints in your DB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use the `@OneToMany(orphanRemoval = true)`
It provides a way to delete orphaned entities from the database.
So, it should remove the FloorPlanEntity from database when it's removed from the list.
There is some tutorial with explanation:
https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-cascade-remove-vs-orphanremoval#orphanremoval

Comment: have you read about the constraint? that field in his parent record  can not be null. that's the problem.

Comment: Yep.
In this case with `orphanRemoval = true` it should work next way:
When you clean the list and save the parent entity, Hibernate will remove the corresponding entities from floor_plans. So, there will be no rows in the table with null id. (With your current config it just removes the value of the `property_id` column from the child enitites )

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/5730762/alexander-terekhov. nope it didn't work I added orphan removal true then made propertyEntity.getFloorPlans().clear() then saved proepertyEntity the same error

Comment: Ok thanks a lot it worked,but I deleted not null constraint then it worked